# Remote login terminal

Tags: linux, security, login, tty

I have an unusual request. I have a box - running Fedora 19 - that I'm using as a server. I have a crappy Atom netbook - also running Fedora - that isn't good for anything. I was wondering if there is any way to set up that netbook as dummy 'physical tty' or thin client login box? The two are connected via LAN.

I'm not referring to SSH, per se. More like a local login service on the netbook that is serving/served by the server. Think more like how you would use a serial port on a headless machine. Except, of course, a netbook doesn't have serial (maybe some insane serial-over-ip setup?). But the same idea; the netbook is basically an agent for the server login service.

Does that make sense? The explanation, not the idea. I know the idea is a bit crazy.

**Edit:** I should probably have mentioned the use case. Basically, my research lab runs everything off of the one box. When they need local access, I'd rather not let that access bee *too* local. But I want it to look and feel as much like they were at the actual console as possible. Some of them get confused easily. Also, neither the box nor the netbook run X11. The server can't afford the overhead, and the netbook... is a netbook.

Comment: why not use a usb to serial adapter?

Comment: Why not? I run Fedora 20 on a netbook - and even run virtual machines within it! It's not so bad. Anyway, I think you are looking for XDMCP.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace one or more of your vty configs with, instead of a local shell, a telnet or SSH command to your server. I recommend not putting your password into the init config for it for obvious reasons. When you switch to that vty, it will connect; perhaps requiring a keystroke to re-attempt if it's sitting at a timed-out connection.

> More like a local login service on the netbook that is serving/served
>   by the server.

That *is* SSH, as near as I can understand your question. Being remote, without an out-of-band management card like an iLO or serial (perhaps over IP, as you stated), you can only connect to the OS, not the physical console, obviously.

Comment: I like it. Maybe replace the vty with a script/program that prompts and waits for a username to be entered then launches ssh with that name. It can visually emulate a terminal login, and SSH still handles authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Linux Terminal Server Project](http://www.ltsp.org/). With X11, you should be able to run an X11 server (the part of X11 that draws stuff on the screen) on your netbook and whatever X11 clients (firefox, libreoffice, almost anything, really, except software that needs direct access to hardware (OpenGL) or pushes a lot of stuff over from the client to server (video?)) you wish on your server, displaying their windows on your netbook.